# Show Message on first launch after install

Tags: android

I want to show a message after the first launch of the app telling about the new features, each time a user installs a new version.

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have an activity for this, that checks if a preference has the value of the current version. If so proceed to the next activity. Otherwise störe the current version in the preference, show the what's new screen and then on button press procees to the next activity

Comment: how do I get my version number at runtime?

Comment: Code it in into a constant. Or ask the PackageManager for the metadata of your package. See e.g. http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Developers/2010-01/msg03487.html

Answer (score 5):

I used this. It was posted by another stackoverflow member I don't recall who. Sorry. Call this code from `onCreate()`

```
// Show changelog
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    PackageInfo pInfo;
    try {
        pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        if (prefs.getLong("lastRunVersionCode", 0) < pInfo.versionCode) {
            showDialog(DIALOG_CHANGELOG);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putLong("lastRunVersionCode", pInfo.versionCode);
            editor.commit();
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error reading versionCode");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's simple. 
On the first start show an [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) and create a record in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Whatever - flag or a string, or somewhat.
The next time your application is started just check that you have this flag in preferences. If there is no one, then this is a first start and it's time to show a dialog =)

Comment: And you should probably store your version number in the preferences, then you can also detect a upgrade [if (running_version > preferences_stored_version) ] .

Comment: when I upgrade the software and reinstall do I lose my preferences? I didn't think so

Answer (score 0):

You have to save somewhere a value which you can check on each startup whether the app was already started. SharePreferences would be a option. Or within a database.

Answer (score 0):

if the user clears application data in the device settings then this all gets reset.