# Give a hint to user at the time of installation time only

Tags: android

I am doing a project in which,i have to give the user a message at the time of installation only.After that the message should be hidden.Now whenever i run the program the message will be displayed.I want to avoid it. I want to do it programatically in android.Can anyone help to resolve this issue?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you trying to display a message on the first run or during installation?

Comment: [This has already been asked.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908840/show-message-on-first-launch-after-install)

Answer (score 0):

You can save a flag into the app database or userPreferences and after displaying the message you can set the flag to false or 0 . Anytime the user starts the app you check that flag and see if you have to display it again or not...

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor edt = settings.edit();

        edt.putBoolean("Accepted", true);
        edt.commit();
boolean isTOSAccepted = settings.getBoolean("Accepted", false);
```